# Magento - Simple Configurable Products Extension question?

Tags: magento

Has anyone had any experience of using the Simple Configurable Products extension on Magento - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products

If so how would I set up a product to be priced on height x width dynamically?

Or if anyone knows of a way that we can achieve the same outcome tha would be great.

p.s. I'm running Magento 1.4.2.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that extension you would have to create and price a simple product for every *height X width* combination you offer, each would need to fill in a matching height and width attribute. Then associate all those simple products with one configurable product.
It is that configurable which customers will see and interact with.