# Magento - Pricing Matrix?

Tags: magento

Does anyone know of an easy way of setting up a price matrix in Magento?

For example Height x Width = price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have discrete size steps, this is as easy as using the plugin you mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462177/). Think screw sizes (limited number of sizes, each represented in stock). If you want to do truly customizable width and height, there is no built-in feature that I'm aware of that is equipped to do this.

Could you use a set width and a variable height (or vice versa)? That would work with product options.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I had a customer requested the same task, to calculate the product price using the width and length custom options. I found [magento price formula extension](https://www.itoris.com/magento-product-price-formula.html) and my customer is happy now.